# Understanding how to store individual digits from a larger sequence in ARM

Tags: arm, endianness

I am working with Big Endian 7 ARM architecture, and I am having trouble understanding how best to extract individual digits from a number sequence.

for example, a UPC code like

UPC DCB "013800150738",

how would I pull let's say the 3rd digit and store it for calculation purposes?

I tried messing around with LDRB, but I can't figure out how to pull a specific digit out

Comment: Probably something like `ldrb r0, [r1, #2]`.  Maybe followed by `sub r0, r0, #'0'` if you want the numerical value instead of the ASCII code.  But without seeing how you receive the string as input, or what exactly you want to do with the digit, it's hard to say.  Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Hey Nate, what I want to do with the code is essentially create a UPC verification software, but I need to pull specific digits to do that. so far, my code is essentially just setting up values MOV r1, #0. I think the ldrb method should work, i'll do some testing right away, thank you for the response!

Comment: you read the back in the reverse of how you put them in there.  you have provided no information.  presumably you would store this as either ascii bytes and then it just becomes a string like any other, or nibbles one for each digit...but it is all up to you as to how you want to store it.

Comment: most readers will type the number into the computer as if it were typed on a keyboard so it would come in as a string, big or little endian does not matter so long as you save it normally with software it will just be a string and you can just ldrb to read it